# NodeJS how-to require module which injects a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js, webpack

I am using webpack to bundle a visualisation built with d3 and a [d3.slider](http://github.com/MasterMaps/d3-slider/blob/master/d3.slider.js#L16) module, yet this is a more general problem - how do I require() a module which patches a module (d3 here) with a function (here d3.slider()) ?

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "d3_slider_error",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "main": "",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "d3": "^3.5.15",
    "d3-slider": "git+ssh://git@github.com:MasterMaps/d3-slider.git",
    "webpack": "^1.9.10",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.9.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^1.5.0"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js :

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/main.js", // APP_PATH
    output: {
        filename: 'main.js',
        path: path.resolve('./dist') // BUILD_PATH  
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            //
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        modulesDirectories: ['node_modules']
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({title : "d3-slider-error"})
    ]
};
```

src/main.js:

```
var d3 = require('d3');
require('d3.slider');

var timeSlider = d3.slider();

console.log("Done!");
```

This logs: TypeError: d3.slider is not a function

Comment: [Working example here](https://github.com/MasterMaps/d3-slider/blob/master/index.html)

Comment: This is not a modular solution using webpack

Comment: With requirejs, you would use a shim. I am fairly new to Webpack, but [this](https://gist.github.com/xjamundx/b1c800e9282e16a6a18e#a-loader-for-every-shim) seems to describe the equivalent of requirejs' shim in Webpack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an ugly'ish solution, but since nothing else came up, I'm posting it here. I add this to package.json dependencies:

```
"script-loader": "git+ssh://git@github.com:webpack/script-loader.git"
```

Then somewhere, for example in the entry point (assuming that d3.slider is in node_modules):

```
require("script!d3.slider");
```

Script-loader executes the script in the global environment once. Should work for all similar problems, legacy scripts etc. Done.

Comment: what do you mean "Then somewhere, for example in the entry point"

Comment: In whatever file you specify as  "main" in you package.json.