# How to integrate Requirejs, d3, and d3.slider module

Tags: javascript, d3.js, requirejs

This post is in reference to a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35454182/nodejs-how-to-require-module-which-injects-a-function) about NodeJS and requiring a module which injects a function.  However, the previous question is in the context of Webpack.  I too am trying to integrate d3.js and the d3.slider module, but using RequireJS.

According to the comment left by [Nikos Paraskevopoulos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2764255/nikos-paraskevopoulos) a shim is needed.  I have not successfully implemented the shim needed for the d3.slider module and was hoping someone could lead me in the right direction.  Right now I have

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        "d3": "https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min",
        "d3.slider": "lib/d3.slider"
    },
    shim: {
        "d3.slider": {
            "deps": ["d3"],
            "exports": "d3"
        }
    }
});
require(['d3'], function(d3) {
    console.log(d3.version);
    d3.select("#time_slider").call(d3.slider());
});
```

This logs:

3.5.17

TypeError: d3.slider is not a function

I think my problem is in the shim, but I'm not quite sure.  Any direction is appreciated.

Comment: Were the last two lines inside a `require(['d3.slider'], function(d3) { ... })`?

Comment: my apologies, the last two lines are require(['d3'], function(d3) { ... }) I'll update the post to reflect that. When I tried your suggestion, the console logs: _undefined_ and _d3.select is not a function_

Answer (score 0):

When I look at the source code of [`d3.slider`](https://github.com/MasterMaps/d3-slider/blob/master/d3.slider.js) I see it calls `define`. So you do not need a `shim` for it.

Also, you are not loading it. You should do this:

```
require(['d3', 'd3.slider'], function (d3) {
    console.log(d3.version);
    d3.select("#time_slider").call(d3.slider());
});
```

In the source I see that it installs itself on `d3`. So you do not need to add a parameter to your anonymous function: once loaded it will be available on the `d3` object.

Comment: Ok, I got rid of the shim and I'm now loading d3.slider however I still get the same output as in my post.  I understand that d3.slider functions should be available on the d3 object, so I don't understand why I'm still getting the TypeError